# Can't find bundle for base name data1

Tags: properties, struts, resourcebundle

I recently working with Struts1，and I am so confused about this error.
I have done with [add class folder] in Java build path, so actually the 'config' folder might be classpath right?
why does ResourceBundle can't read 'data1.properties'?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CtSfz.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to SO, Please don't post [pictures in question](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). Also visit [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)..

Comment: Sure, it *might* be. But we don't *know* that it is. In general it's best to put it where it belongs--or adjust the path so it ends up in the right place.